# Issue getting index field from hazelcast using predicate

Tags: hazelcast, nosql

I am trying to match a field that is not a key with a remote hazelcast, the goal here is to create many remote instances and use it to store serialized objects.

what i noticed is that if i do both put and SQL in the same run, the return works, as follow :

my class

```
public class Provider implements Serializable {

private String resourceId;
private String first;

public String getResourceId() {
    return resourceId;
}

public void setResourceId(String resourceId) {
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
}

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
 }

}
```

code :

```
    /*********** map initlization ************/
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress(host + ":" + port);

    instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    map =  instance.getMap("providerWithIndex");

    String first = "XXXX"
    /***** adding item ***************/
    Provider provider = new Provider();
    provider.setResourceId("11111");
    provider.setFirst( first);
    map.put(provider);
    /********** getting items ************/
    EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
    Predicate predicate =  e.get( "first" ).equal( first ) ;
    Collection<Provider> providers =  map.values(predicate);
```

once i run both put and get in different runs, the result is 0 - so to the same code i get no response.

my only thought is that it only does local fetch and not remote. but i hope i have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, apart from the fact that you can't do `map.put(provider)`, you need to pass a key, so like `map.put(someKey, provider);`
The query looks & works fine.